# Flutter: iOS rich image notification is not working in firebase messaging

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using the firebase flutter  `firebase_messaging: ^6.0.9` with google official documentation almost no solution to get rich ios image notification.

what I have tried:

I found that in react native developers used this

> using the Extensions Framework you can use the
>   CarnivalNotificationServiceExtension class to handle the default
>   implementation for you

looking for the similar solution in google firebase_messaging

references for the issue:

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/357 (long time still unresolved)

https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/111

https://docs.mobile.sailthru.com/docs/ios-rich-push

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: update you soon need to work on this

Comment: @LOG_TAG Rich notifications don't work for me, even in Android, I'm using firebase_messaging: ^11.4.0, would you tell me how you made it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a notification service extension as described [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration#advanced-optional-allowing-notification-images)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but the linked answer is in obective-c

The Following worked for me:

Step 1 - [Add a notification service extension](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/#step-1---add-a-notification-service-extension)

Step 2 - [Add Target to Podfile](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/#step-2---add-target-to-the-podfile)

Step 3 - [Use Extension Helper](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/#step-3---use-the-extension-helper)

Converted to Swift:

```
//
//  NotificationService.swift
//  RichNotification
//

import UserNotifications

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {
    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?
    
    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
        
        guard let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent,
              let attachmentURLAsString = bestAttemptContent.userInfo["image"] as? String,
              let attachmentURL = URL(string: attachmentURLAsString) else {
            return
        }
        
        downloadImageFrom(url: attachmentURL) { (attachment) in
            if let attachment = attachment {
                bestAttemptContent.attachments = [attachment]
                contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
            }
        }
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }
    
    private func downloadImageFrom(url: URL, with completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationAttachment?) -> Void) {
        let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { (downloadedUrl, response, error) in
            // 1. Test URL and escape if URL not OK
            guard let downloadedUrl = downloadedUrl else {
                completionHandler (nil)
                return
            }
            // 2. Get current's user temporary directory path
            var urlPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory ())
            // 3. Add proper ending to url path, in the case jpg (The system validates the content of attached files before scheduling the corresponding notification request. If an attached file is corrupted,
            let uniqueURLEnding = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString + ".jpg"
            urlPath = urlPath.appendingPathComponent (uniqueURLEnding)
            // 4. Move downloadedUrl to newly created urlPath
            try? FileManager.default.moveItem(at: downloadedUrl, to: urlPath)
            // 5. Try adding getting the attachment and pass it to the completion handler
            do {
                let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment (identifier: "picture", url: urlPath, options: nil)
                completionHandler(attachment)
            }
            catch {
                completionHandler(nil)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

extension UNNotificationRequest {
    var attachment: UNNotificationAttachment? {
        guard let attachmentURL = content.userInfo["image"] as? String, let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: attachmentURL)!) else {
            return nil
        }
        return try? UNNotificationAttachment(data: imageData, options: nil)
    }
}

extension UNNotificationAttachment {
    convenience init(data: Data, options: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) throws {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let temporaryFolderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let temporaryFolderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(temporaryFolderName, isDirectory: true)

        try fileManager.createDirectory(at: temporaryFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        let imageFileIdentifier = UUID().uuidString + ".jpg"
        let fileURL = temporaryFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(imageFileIdentifier)
        try data.write(to: fileURL)
        try self.init(identifier: imageFileIdentifier, url: fileURL, options: options)
    }
}
```

cURL to send push notification via Firebase/FCM

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' \
--header 'Authorization: key=<YOUR FCM KEY>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "to": "fcm token for device or channel id",
    "content_available": true,
    "mutable_content": true,
    "notification": {
        "title": "Notification With Image",
        "mutable-content": true,
        "body": "Test Message "
    }, 
    "data": {
        "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_%28JPEG-HDR%29.jpg"
    }
}'
```